# Is it possible to use complex selector inside :not() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to select and count some elements on Trello page. I would like to do all this stuff in one line, using something like this:

```
$('.js-list.list-wrapper').each(function(index){
  var numberOfTickets = $(this).find('.list-card:not(div > .list-card-details > .list-card-title:contains("LIMIT: 8"))').length;        
});
```

So I want to select all `.list-card` from each column but not these which contains **"LIMIT: 8"** text inside `.list-card-title`. Theoretically, it should work well but I cannot find usages, like I showed above, on the internet. Is it proper to use it like that?

EDIT:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hr9cpc1m/

Comment: can you show me your html sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in conjunction with [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
var numberOfTickets = $(this).find('.list-card:not(:has(div > .list-card-details > .list-card-title:contains("LIMIT: 8")))').length;
```

Comment: But if I use `:has` the `.list-card-title` class shouldn't be the nearest child of `.list-card` ?

Comment: @Dominik, You can use selector as per your requirement

Comment: Thank You! It works. According to https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/ `:has()` is looking on all descendants, not just on a direct child.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to make this easier to read

```
var numberOfTickets = $(this).find('.list-card').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('.list-card-title:contains("LIMIT: 8")').length;
}).length;
```